# How to upload files to different host?

Tags: php, laravel

Application A is hosted on `abc-web.host.net` and from application A user upload images to host using and upload controller using this method to upload files

`$file->move(public_path('file'), $fileName);`

this upload files to  `abc-web.host.net/file` directory, but i need to upload the files to

`abc.host.net/file` I tried to use directly `abc.host.net` on `move()` but it doesn't work.

How can I upload the files to `abc.host.net` host ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using url you cant upload file to another host. So you have to define file system for that `FTP` or `SFTP`

Create a `filesystem` in `config/filesystems.php`

```
'ftp' => [
    'driver' => 'ftp',
    'host' => 'ftp.example.com',
    'username' => 'your-username',
    'password' => 'your-password',

    // Optional FTP Settings...
    // 'port' => 21,
    // 'root' => '',
    // 'passive' => true,
    // 'ssl' => true,
    // 'timeout' => 30,
],
```

While uploading

```
Storage::disk('ftp')->put('avatars/1', $content);
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#ftp-driver-configuration